# Use py2exe or nuitka in the case of embedded python

Tags: python, c++

I have embedded python in a C++ program .How can the compiled C++ program run without python interpreter? This can be done in a 'pure python' program by using freeze or py2exe or nuitka but I don't know how this can be done if python is being embedded in some other language like C++.

Comment: "embedded python" means "embedded interpreter of python"

Comment: btw. `freeze and py2exe gets python interpreter and python script and puts both in .exe file - or rather self-executable .zip file. nuitka convert python to C++ and compile.

Comment: @furas embedding python in a c++ program and running it without python interpreter

Comment: "embedding Python" means "embedded interpreter of Python` so you have Python interpreter inside C++ program.

Comment: @furas I just want to run my hybrid python-C++ program without the need of any python interpreter :)

Comment: you can't run Python code without interpreter (and VM inside interpreter). You can have build-in interpreter in C++ program or you have to convert Python to C/C++.

Comment: How can I have a built-in interpreter in c++ program?

Comment: interpreter of Python/Lua/other build-in in C/C++/other is called "embedded Python/Lua/other". Python doc: [Embedding Python in Another Application](https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/embedding.html)